# Why some methods are not compiled in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

Why method A is not compiled while methods B and C are ok?

```
class A {

  methodA() {

  }

  void methodB() {


  }

  static methodC() {


  }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the "def" modifier in groovy if you are not declaring a type for the method:

```
class A {
    def methodA() {
    }
}
```

should work.